# How can I set a Map field in my properties without having to list each key/value pair individually?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

I have a Spring Boot Application with a service that has a `Map <String, List<String>>` field. The map is fetched from a properties file where it is set as follows:

```
mapField.key1[0]=value10
mapField.key1[1]=value11
mapField.key1[2]=value12
mapField.key2[0]=value20
```

How can I set it up as follows:

```
mapField={key1=[value10, value11, value12], key2=[value20]}
```

without running into a conversion error:

```
Failed to bind properties under 'mapField' to Map<String, List<String>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mapping is a little bit more complicated, so I would suggest to define a ConfigurationProperties.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class MapFieldConfig {

    private Map<String,List<String>> myMap;

    public Map<String, List<String>> getMyMap() {
        return myMap;
    }

    public void setMyMap(Map<String, List<String>> myMap) {
        this.myMap = myMap;
    }
}
```

in this way you can just autowire the new object containing the target configuration :

```
@Autowired
MapFieldConfig mapFieldConfig;
```

Your application.properties file will be:

```
myMap.key1=a,b,c
myMap.key2=d,c,f
```